# MVC 4 integrating jQuery DatePicker in aspx file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I'm using a aspx file because of my ReportViewer control and my jQuery datepicker from a asp:TextBox doesn't pop-up.

How can I display a DatePicker in the TextBox ?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListAgenti" runat="server" DataTextField="nume" DataValueField="id_agent" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceHelios" />                     
        From  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFrom" Width="80"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        To    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxTo" Width="80" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="Display" runat="server" onclick="Display_Click" Text="Display" />

        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewerAgentvanz" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Width="800px" Height="800px"  InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)"   />
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerAgentvanz" runat="server" />

        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourceHelios" runat="server" EnableFlattening="False" 
            ConnectionString="name=HeliosEntities" DefaultContainerName="HeliosEntities" EntitySetName="agenti"
            Select="it.[id_agent], it.[nume]" OrderBy="it.nume ASC" Where="it.active = TRUE">
        </asp:EntityDataSource>        
    </div>
</form>
```

Other workaround - Can I display a rdlc reportviewer in a razor page(*.cshtml) ?

I have jQuery 1.7.2, Nuget 1.7 and for my razor textbox I have a Editor Template

EDIT : link to the html file : [click](http://www.arhimedes.ro/misi/VanzariForm.zip)

Comment: We need to see the Javascript and the HTML generated by the ASPX page

Comment: I've added a link to my html file. thank you :)

Comment: I don't see any references to jQuery in your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not included the JQuery library, the JQueryUI library or the JQueryUI CSS files.

Add this to the `<head>` of your document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To display a jquery datepicker in the textbox, just do:

```
$(function () {
    $("#TextBoxTo").datepicker();
    $("#TextBoxFrom").datepicker();
});
```

Now, your question about report viewing in a razor page, I'm afraid that's not possible. In order to view a report you need the `ReportViewer` control (which you have used in your code) and you can't use ASP.NET controls in Razor.

Comment: It may want to be $("input[id$='TextBoxTo']").datepicker(); as .net will produce a unquie id for you so doing the above means you want to apply a datepicker to any inputs which have id ENDING WITH "TextboxTo"

Comment: @Steve Yeah good point, but looking at his generated markup (he's attached a HTML file), the ID is exactly `TextBoxTo` :)

Answer (score 0):

You've not included the JQuery library, the JQueryUI library or the JQueryUI CSS files.

Add this to the  of your document: